# meteor owl-carousel rerun when session variable change

Tags: jquery, meteor

I have a page with a list of project.

When I click a project of the list, a modal box opens with a carousel of images linked to this project.

This is my template:

```
template(name="projects")
    #projects.page
        h1 Projets en cours
        section.feature-columns.row.clearfix
            each projects
                article.feature-col.col-md-4
                    a(href="#" class="project-item thumbnail linked")
                        with first_image
                            img(src="{{url}}" alt="{{_id}}" class="item-thumbnail")
                        .caption
                            h5 #{name}
                            p {{trimString description 100}}
    #common-modal.modal.fade.in
        .modal-dialog
            .modal-content
                button(class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true") x
                .modal-body
                    with project
                        h1 {{name}}
                        p #{description}
                        .popup-image-gallery.owl-carousel.owl-theme
                            each images
                                .item
                                    img(src="{{url}}" alt="{{_id}}" width="100%")
```

This is the helper I use to open the modal box:

```
Template.projects.events
  "click .project-item": (e,instance) ->
    Session.set "currentProject", @_id
    $("#common-modal").modal("show")
    if owl
      owl.destroy()
    setTimeout( ->
      @owl = $("#common-modal .popup-image-gallery").owlCarousel
        autoPlay: 5000
        stopOnHover: true
        navigation: false
        paginationSpeed: 1000
        goToFirstSpeed: 2000
        singleItem: true
        lazyLoad: true
        autoHeight: true
        transitionStyle: "fade"
    , 1500)
```

This works when I click the first project.

When I click another project though, I doesn't work anymore.

It is obviously because I should kill the first carousel and then initialise the new one but I don't know how to do this.

Any help?

thanks.

Comment: You might find this answer useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354070/meteor-call-function-after-template-is-rendered-with-data/25354404#25354404

Comment: Thanks, It put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

After different attempts, I came to this solution:

First, I store my image ids in a session variable

```
  images: ->
    ids = ProjectImages.find({project_id: @_id}).map (u) ->
      u.image_id
    c = Session.get "carousel_images"
    Session.set "ids", ids
    Images.find({_id: {$in: ids} })
```

Then I create a tracker bound to this session variable which destroys and recreates the Carousel every time the data changes:

```
Template.projects.rendered = ->
  Tracker.autorun ->
    Session.get "ids"
    owl = $("#common-modal .popup-image-gallery")
    owl.data("owlCarousel").destroy() if owl.data("owlCarousel")
    setTimeout( ->
      owl.owlCarousel
        autoPlay: 5000
        stopOnHover: true
        navigation: false
        paginationSpeed: 1000
        goToFirstSpeed: 2000
        singleItem: true
        lazyLoad: true
        autoHeight: true
        transitionStyle: "fade"
    , 500)
```

Hope this helps someone...